# Least Squares with Inequality Constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, least-squares, karush-kuhn-tucker

I want to use Least Squares to minimize $Ax-b$ (overdetermined system), subject to $x_1+x_2+x_3=1$ and $\forall x_i, 0 \leq x_i \leq 1$. As per my understanding, I need to set up the Lagrange function and then check KKT conditions. How do I set up this problem in matrix notation and what would KKT conditions be in this case? My linear algebra is rudimentary and I can set this problem up and solve it in "regular" notation (up to inequality constraints). But I need to implement it in Python so I want to understand how it's done in matrix notation.

Comment: $Ax$ is a vector, so hard to understand how you minimize it, unless you mean find $x$ that minimizes sum of squared component-wise errors.

Comment: @User5678 if I understood you correctly, yes. $Ax-b$ are errors and they should be minimized

Comment: any reason you want to least squares vs least absolute value?

Comment: easier to implement. i am planning to solve the system with `numpy` Python library which has convenient methods for solving such systems

Comment: One option, if you are ok using scipy, I'd recommend recasting as a minimize sum of deviations vs squared deviations and express it as a linear program. If you want to stay with least squares, you'll have some issue with the box constraints

Comment: yeah this problem is easy to solve with scipy or cvxpy, but i need to solve it with numpy because this problem needs to be part of numba JITed function (which only supports numpy)

Answer (score 3):

You have two sets of constraints:

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1$

$x_i \in [0,1]\;\forall i$

In matrix notation you'd get something like this:

$\min \;\;(Ax-b)^T(Ax-b)$

$s.t.$

$1^Tx=1$

$x \geq 0$

$x \leq 1$

So you'd add your slack *vectors* $s,t$ and multipliers $\lambda$ (scalar) and $\phi,\mu$ (vectors) to get:

$$L(x,\lambda, \phi)= (Ax-b)^T(Ax-b) -\lambda(1^Tx-1) - \phi^T(x-s) + \mu^T(x+t) $$

KKT are per usual:

1. $\nabla L = \mathbf{0}$
2. All constraints satisfied
3. Either $\phi_i=0$ or $s_i = 0$ but not both (complementary slackness)

Comment: what is $s$ in this case? also how to differentiate this? (again, sorry im not very good with matrix notation)

Comment: First, there is a mistake I made -- I left out a constraint $x\leq 1$ and its associated lagrange term.

Regardless -- $s$ (and now $t$) are the slack variables associated with the non-negativity and $\leq 1$ constraints, respectively.

There is one slack variable per variable, but we collect them into a vector (just like $x$) to leverage vector-matrix notation.

Comment: Isn't $x \leq 1$ constraint redundant, because of the $1^T x=1$ and $x \geq 1$ constraints (i.e. $1^T x=1$ implies that no $x_i$ can be greater than 1, since no other can be negative)? I set up the system of equations and got $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 2\cdot A^\top \cdot (A\cdot x-b)-(m+ 1^T\lambda \cdot \mathbb{1}-\phi) \\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} = -(1^Tx-1)\cdot \mathbb{1} \\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi} = x-s \\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mu} = -(t+x)$. But when it tried to solve it, it said that I got a singular matrix. Where did I make the mistake?

Comment: Yes, you are correct :) the limit on sums and non-negativity imply it -- nice catch

Comment: why the dot product in $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda}$? $\lambda$ is a scalar

Comment: also, the other two should be $-(x-s)$ and $(t+x)$ respecitvely

Comment: I'd also double-check the first partial derivative wrt x

Comment: @cc88 — any luck?